# Numerous Time Machine errors with new WD drive - where to start?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, catalina, external-disk

So ive had this WD easy store 10tb external drive for 2 weeks now with a 2019 16" MBP with 10.15.5 Catalina running.  Its formatted Mac OS extended journaled(the xternal drive). Ive got 3 partitions on the eternal drive.  Have been getting all these errors - see below - trouble copying files, can't be ejected, couldn't back up to, could not mount, etc...  Apple has said I can't have 3 partitions on an external time machine back up drive, then file corruption.  Its been formatted new, set up in time machine, then all the files moved off(storage files not the backups - I just deleted those and started over as not to be moving around time machine back ups), reformatted and set up again as Mac OS extended journaled and rechecked in disk utility as well as the wd app file check and Ive started new back ups and still get these error.  Now HD is saying I can use a hub to go through to the thunderbolt connection as the drive is usb c. WD also told me no on the partitioned drive. All sounds like malarky to me as I used an older partitioned wd with the same hyperdrive hub w/ no issues.  FWIW on my older iMac the external WD connected directly to the computer.

Any ideas where I can look to see what's causing these errors?

[image: backup failed]
[image: error]
[image: ejected]
[image: could not mount]
[image: info]

Comment: Did you try with a different cable?

Comment: so now im in the process of using a lightning to usbc adapter to see what happens.  I called HyperDrive and after going round and round with the girl, she said she talked to a senior tech and that supposedly the 9 in 1 dongle has a 2 TB limitation and that I need to buy any of the 6, 7 or 8 in 2 models.  She kinda seemed like she didn't know what she was talking about and if there is a 2tb limit, why doesnt it say so anywhere?     https://www.hypershop.com/collections/usb-c-hubs .  Weird....

Comment: so I called belkin to ck and see if one of there products would work w/ the 10tb: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1551301-REG/belkin_f4u092btsgy_usb_c_multimedia_hub_power.html/overview. I was told probably not.  So why won't these work w/ externally powered drive?  Whats the point of having it if they won't work on laptops but don't say they won't ?  The laptops don't say not to use 10 TB drives and the drives don't say cant be used w/ laptops and hubs.  Furthermore the drive doesnt say anywhere on the packages that they will not support hub use.  What gives?

Comment: so I continue to get the same error messages using an apple cable to connect the drive. USB to USBC.  The apple tech did call back last week to say the error, according to the logs, was a kernel crash being caused somewhere between the external drive and the computer??